# Number generator, but within a range that the user put in. Java

Tags: java, random, numbers, range, generator

Hi i am new to java and stackoverflow. I am trying to create a program that asks for the user to input a range and it will create a random number list within the users range. It looks like this.

```
package numbergenerator;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numbergenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        int int1;
        int int2;
        int answer;
        int numbers;


        System.out.println("Enter your min range number: ");
        int1 = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your max range number: ");
        int2 = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many numbers do ya want? ");
        numbers = s.nextInt();

        for(int counter=0; counter<numbers; counter++);
        answer = int1 < r > int2;
        //this doesn't work. 
        //And i know it is improper syntax, but then what is the proper syntax?
        System.out.println(answer);

    }

}
```

I am having problems with how to get the random number. Let me know if you have an idea. Also i might have the for loop messed up as well, so just let me know. thanks.

Comment: Calculate the range (max - min), calculate a random number from 0-range, add min

Comment: You also have a bug with for(int counter=0; counter<numbers; counter++); - no semicolon needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  package numbergenerator;

    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class numbergenerator {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random r = new Random();

            int int1;
            int int2;
            int answer;
            int numbers;


            System.out.println("Enter your min range number: ");
            int1 = s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter your max range number: ");
            int2 = s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("How many numbers do ya want? ");
            numbers = s.nextInt();

            for(int counter=0; counter<numbers; counter++){
            answer =r.nextInt(int2-int1)+int1;

            System.out.println(answer);
}

        }

    }
```

Comment: The 'answer = ...' and 'System.out ...' lines need to be in the scope of the for loop (ie curly braces as in the OP). As written, the for loop has no effect on the output of the program and only one answer would be generated and displayed.

Comment: this will never generate a number equal to the upper limit (int2) modify to answer =r.nextInt(int2-int1 +1)+int1; so you get the correct range

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the range of numbers you need...

```
// Make sure we only have positive numbers...not sure if that's a requirement
// bet lets make life easier
int int1 = Math.abs(int1);
int int2 = Math.abs(int2);
int range = Math.abs(int2 - int1);
```

Calculate your random number within that range...

```
int answer = r.nextInt(range);
```

Add your lower range to it...

```
answer += Math.min(int1, int2);
```

*nb:* You should know, that this will only generate random numbers between `min` to `max - 1`.  If you want to include `max`, you will need to add `1` to the range...

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. It's a great solution.

Comment: I "think" maybe because it will only generate numbers in the range of min-(max - 1), but that requirement hasn't been stated...

Comment: You could also use Math.abs(int2 - int1) if you want to ensure that the range is positive and don't trust the user to follow the instructions :)

Comment: @jbeck True, but you should also be using `Math.min(...) - Math.max(...)` ;) - One would question if that was outside the scope of the question though ;)

Comment: @jbeck Ah, no wait, I think I see what you mean :P

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following values:

```
int max;
int min;
```

If you want to get a new random number between max and min, you need to understand how the Random class works.

nextInt(int n) returns a number that is greater than or equal than zero, and less than(but not equal to) n.

Therefore, if you want to get a number between max and min, inclusive of both, you would have to do the following:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomNumber=r.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package numbergenerator;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numbergenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rn = new Random();

        int int1;
        int int2;
        int answer;
        int numbers;


        System.out.println("Enter your min range number: ");
        int1 = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your max range number: ");
        int2 = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many numbers do ya want? ");
        numbers = s.nextInt();

        for(int counter=0; counter<numbers; counter++);
        {
              int n = int1 - int2 + 1;
              int i = rn.nextInt() % n;
              randomNum =  int1 + i;
              System.out.println(randomNum );
        }
    }
}
```